# how to save array of images with Realm

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

i'm trying to save several arrays of images using realm but i'm not sure where to start. i've looked at the realm docs and a few tutorials but none really help me with what i'm trying to do, i'm new to ios so i might just not be able to make any connections with what they say and what i want to do. what i have is 2 viewcontrollers with 5 different arrays that populate 5 different collectionviews. all the research i've done says i need to make a data model for the data i want to store, but i'm not sure how to do that, because the user takes the image i want to store using the imagepickercontroller. if some one could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

so far ive tried this:

```
 //the class of vc1 
 class CViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, ClosetDelegate, Object

 //where i tried saving the array(im not sure if this works because of the error i get when i inherit 'Object') 
 override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    let realm = Realm()
    realm.write{
        realm.add(array1)
    }

}
```

i get this error "multiple inheritance from classes uiviewcontroller and Object" when i try to inherit 'Object'

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a thorough read-through of the [Realm Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/).

Theoretically, you'd have a Realm model with an NSData property to persist the image data. Unfortunately,

> NSData properties cannot hold data exceeding 16MB in size. To store larger amounts of data, either break it up into 16MB chunks or store it directly on the file system, storing paths to these files in the realm. An exception will be thrown at runtime if your app attempts to store more than 16MB in a single property.

---

As a side note, you're probably getting that multiple inheritance warning because your View Controller is subclassing Object, which is unnecessary.